# Sorting with PHP and GET method?

Tags: php, sorting, methods, get

I'm trying to make a sorting, using links and `GET` method with them. I'll provide the code first and then explain what I'm trying to achieve. There could be a better way by using AJAX, and making it dynamic (I think?), but I want to start off with this first.

Code:

```
if(isset($_GET['order'])){$order = $_GET['order'];}else{$order = 0;}
if(isset($_GET['field'])){$order_field = $_GET['field'];}

switch($order)
{
    case 0: 
        $order_next = "DESC";
        break;
    case "DESC":
        $order_next = "ASC";
        break;
    case "ASC":
        $order_next = 0;
        break;
}
```

And later, in the HTML page I have this snippet:

```
<? 
if($order == 0)
{
    printf("<a href='admin.php?field=lastname&order=%s'>Last</a>
    ", $order_next);
}
else
{
    printf("<a href='admin.php?field=%s&order=%s'>Last</a><a class='sort_desc' href='admin.php?field=%s&order=%s'></a>
    ", $order_field, $order_next, $order_field, $order_next);
}
?>
```

Okay. I have a link **Last**, which should have 3 positions, *default*, *DESC* order, *ASC* order.
When I click on it once, it should send via GET method, that the field I clicked was "Lastname" field, and I need the next position (from default (without sorting) to next one (DESC in this case)). I can't quite catch the error on the code, or I don't understand something, doesn't the page reload properly or something? When I click the link, the `$order` and `$order_field` is read from the GET method, but **nothing else happens**. The `switch` doesn't work for some reason, and `$order_next` doesn't change into the new value, and there is only 1 link, instead of 2:
Default: Link "Last"
DESC: Link "Last" + link with the triangle picture pointing down.

P.S: Sorry if I might not explain this too well, but I tried. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `case 0:` to `case "0":` and all will be good with the world :-)

This is because switch uses [Loose Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)

To understand why, just run this code and see the result:

```
var_dump("DESC" == 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this already made part of it work! Thanks you so much! P.S: Got the second part working too!

Comment: @Arno - I would rather that you do a `if($order == "0")`

Answer (score 0):

Change the test comparison from:

```
if($order == 0)
```

to

```
if($order === 0)
```

Comment: And this answered the second question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your Switch statement is getting caught each time on case 0. If you change your 0 in the code to "0"  as follows:

```
$order = "0";
case "0":
if($order == "0")
```

it will work as planned :)